# Как подключить VK SDK на swift?

Tags: ios, swift, vkontakte-api

Мне надо подключить vk sdk на swift. Хочу через него использовать авторизацию пользователей,для получение токена и потом чтобы работать API.

Comment: пригодился ответ?

Answer (score 3):

VK iOS SDK можно установить с помощью Cocoa pods. Для этого добавьте в Ваш pod-файл следующую строчку:

```
pod "VK-ios-sdk"
```

Также рекомендую добавить в самом начале pod-файла следующую строчку (или убрать её из-под комментария):

```
use_frameworks!
```

Библиотеку на языке Objective-C можно подключить к проекту на языке Swift с помощью Bridge Header. В частности эту технику можно применить и для VK iOS SDK.
Однако можно поступить и проще. В частности, можно использовать ключевое слово import и подключить данную библиотеку как модуль.
Далее приведу фрагмент кода для Swift 3/Xcode 8.3.3 с использованием VK iOS SDK (при условии что Вы установили VK iOS SDK как модуль, а не собираете его вместе с проектом):

```
import VK_ios_sdk
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, VKSdkDelegate, VKSdkUIDelegate {
    let VK_APP_ID = "0000000000000000" // Идентификатор Вашего VK-приложения
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let sdkInstance = VKSdk.initializeWithAppId(self.VK_APP_ID)
        sdkInstance.registerDelegate(self)
        sdkInstance.uiDelegate = self
    }
    // Методы протоколов VK SDK
    func vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinishedWithResult(result:VKAuthorizationResult?) -> Void {

    }

    func vkSdkUserAuthorizationFailed() -> Void {

    }

    func vkSdkAccessTokenUpdated(newToken:VKAccessToken?, oldToken:VKAccessToken?) -> Void {

    }

    func vkSdkAuthorizationStateUpdatedWithResult(result:VKAuthorizationResult) -> Void {

    }

    func vkSdkShouldPresentViewController(controller:UIViewController?) -> Void {

    }

    func vkSdkNeedCaptchaEnter(captchaError:VKError?) -> Void {

    }
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, а где брать app id для настройки VK SDK в разделе Standalone приложения на сайте вк? Bundle id вроде бы я нашёл, а вот app id не знаю где брать. Или этот идентификатор дают при регистрации приложения в app store? А как быть на время тестирования? Заранее благодарен за ответ!

Comment: @cheerful_weasel На странице "Для разработчиков" откройте вкладку "Мои приложения". Там найдите требуемое приложение. Затем выберите пункт "Настройки", где первым пунктом значится "ID приложения" - этот ID и есть то что Вам нужно.

Comment: Но это же id приложения в вк, а я имел в виду app id для приложения ios. Просто в вконтакте в разделе "Мои приложения", когда я захожу в настройки своего приложения, там есть пункт "Настройки SDK" и там надо заполнить два поля. Первое поле это "App Bundle id для iOS", а второе поле "App id для iOS". И вот последнее я не знаю где брать.

Comment: Вот скрин: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29604742/sites/all/app_id_screen.PNG

Comment: @cheerful_weasel Минуточку, я Вам написал, где взять идентификатор, который в моём ответе подставляется в значение переменной VK_APP_ID. "App id для iOS" - это идентификатор приложения в магазине, узнать Вы его можете из своей учётной записи в Apple Developer.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.